# Android - JDBC Login

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, authentication

Heres my [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mswqD.jpg) screen. The top editText is "txtbxStudentUsername" and the bottom editText is "txtbxStudentLunchID".

I am using jdbc to conenct to our phpadmin wamp mysql server on the LAN so no over the internet SQL problems.

I know i am having a problem reading the edittext fields in and comparing them in the database. Also the [syntax of my database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAcEL.jpg) Any advice? Here is my code.

```
    public void onGotoStudent(View View)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tardy_system";
        String user = "root_user";
        String pwd = "root";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

        EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbxStudentUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbxStudentLunchID);

        String passChars;

        passChars = password.getText().toString();
        if(passChars!=null) 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost/tardy_system/students","Matt_Glover","root");

            (PreparedStatement) prepstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Username,Lunch_ID FROM Student where username=? and password=?");
            prepstmt.setString(1, username);
            prepstmt.setString(2, password);


            ResultSet rs;
            rs = prepstmt.executeQuery();

            boolean found = rs.next();
            if (found)
              System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            prepstmt.close();
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,username);
        ps.setString(2,password);
        ResultSet rs=password.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
           //found
        }
        else{
           //not found
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two D's for a double dose of pimping?

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to use MySQL driver within an Android app. What I think you must do is writing something in the server side that you can POST request from Android. Something like: http://yourserver.com/login.php

Comment: please note that 'localhost' will be your android device and not your machine in your LAN

Comment: rodger, itll be the static ip our server is set to.

Comment: I ended up shifting like you said to JSON with a php backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not possible to connect with jdbc without an AsynTask